# How to Draw V Letter Shape Using Asterisk(*) in C++

Tags: c++

I want to Draw a Character V in C++. I don't know what to do further to get the required result.

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i, j;
for()
{
    for()
    {
      if(i == j)
      {
        cout << "*";
      }
      else
      {
        cout << " ";
      }
}
cout<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile - you don't have a closing brace for the outer for loop and your for loops don't have bodies (at the very least `;;` is required)

Comment: I know.
i just write it as sample.

Comment: Don't give up! You are more than half-way there. If you write your `for` headers correctly (e.g: `for (int i = 0; i <= height; ++i)`), you'll draw the left-hand-side of the V. To draw the right-hand-side, you need to add an or condition to the `if` statement (like `if (i == j || /* some maths here /* == j)`).

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "*      *\n"
               " *    *\n"
               "  *  *\n"
               "   **\n"
}
```

Comment: Bro , Nice One
But I was to do it Using Nexted For Loop

Comment: Brother Student, you can edit your question to reflect the complete requirements.

Answer (score 0):

i am not big fan of C++ but i try to give the logic

```
#include <iostream.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n; //height of the Char V
    int i, j;
    #char s=""; //i know only to adding string if u add s as string 
    for(int x = 1, y = n ; x <= y ; x++, y--) {
        cout << s;
        cout << "*";
        for(int t = 1 ; t < t ; t++) {
            cout << "";
        }
        cout << "*";
        s=s+"";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void drawPattern(int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int end=height * 2;
    int j=0;
    for ( int start=0;start<height;start++,end--) {
        for ( j=0;j<start;j++){
            System.out.print(" ");  
        }   
        System.out.print("*");
        for ( ;j<end;j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}
```

One dirty implementation in JAVA , try to port it to C++, height can be user input